# Derive ActiveRecord model field from id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'm writing an application to parse my iTunes xml library to an database in Ruby and i'm having an issue... i have a Cover model which has one field, Filename, which i need to derive from another field, Album_ID, in that fashion

Filename = Album_ID left padded by 10 '0's and jpg extension...

But the field ALBUM_ID, as the name suggests, is a foreign key to other model, Album. I only get ALBUM_ID when i save the album...

Is there any way to derive my filename folder to get ALBUM_ID using callbacks, i don't know, perhaps BEFORE_SAVE or AFTER_SAVE?

**--==UPDATE==--**

Let me clarify... i have an field in my COVERS table name FILENAME... this field has to store the filename of the cover, which is in this format

For album with ID 1 = 0000000001.jpg
For album with ID 56 = 0000000056.jpg

Album model has a HAS_MANY relation with Cover model... when i save Album, i need to get the value saved to ALBUM_ID in Cover model and create a string in that format and use it in filename field.

i'm doing, in another part of the application, a sweep in my library folder to copy the covers jpgs to another folder... that's the reason i need to rename the files

Comment: since you have a `has_many` relationship, isn't it possible that all cover entries have the same `jpg` name?

Comment: For each album i have three covers... in the filesystem each cover has a different filename... in my sweep procedure, in which i copy this files, i organize them in separate folders with the same name, which need to reference the album_id

Comment: From my point of view this model serves does not enough purpose to exist. You could easily generate a `helper` to output the filename with the ID of the Album. Then you wouldn't need to worry about the callbacks.

Comment: Or is it about *saving* the image with the correct filename? How do you save the file?

Comment: Jo lagran, could you answer my question, it'll help me find a solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've decided to stop storing the filename in my database and, using an class method, derive the filename from the album_id, as the function below shows

```
def getFilename
   return self.album_id.to_s.rjust(10,'0') + '.jpg'
end
```

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it you have a `Cover` model that `belongs_to` the `Album` model, using the `album_id` field.

When creating an `Album`, you can easily associate relational Models with `.build`

```
album = Album.new(:name => "Foo", :artist => "Bar", ...)
album.cover = Cover.build(:filename => "filename.png")
# save when you're done
album.save
```

Now when you save the `album` the `cover` automatically gets created with the correct `album_id`.

### Second solution

After reading your post again it seems the sole purpose of your `Cover` model is to generate a jpg with the id of the album.

If you have a jpg `00000000001.jgp`, why won't you generate the name in a helper or in the views?

**show.html.erb**

```
<img url="0000000000<%= @album.id%>.jpg"/>
```